# Can you use math calculations on two alias columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to do this:

```
SELECT SUM(currentbalance) AS 'current', SUM(principal) AS 'prin', 'current' + 'prin' AS 'total'
FROM dbase
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
SELECT sum(currentbalance) AS 'current', sum(principal) AS 'prin', (SELECT 'current') + (SELECT 'prin') AS 'total'
FROM dbase
```

@juergen-d @fqhv

Both answers worked perfectly. I thought that would be enough for me to understand how to add it to my current query. How can I implement this inside this query? I need to divide the "file_principal" by the "total_cash_cleared"? Thanks in Advance.

```
SELECT a.portfolio
       ,a.dateplaced
       ,(SELECT SUM(chargedoffprincipal) FROM Dbase WHERE portfolio = a.portfolio ) AS 'file_principal'
       ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus IN ('POSTED','PROCCESED'), paymentamount, 0)) AS 'total_cash_cleared'
       ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING', paymentamount, 0)) AS 'total_cash_pending'
       ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '30_days'
       ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '60_days'
       ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '90_days'
FROM dbase a
LEFT JOIN payments b
ON a.filenumber = b.filenumber
GROUP BY a.portfolio
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(a.dateplaced, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC
```

I tried to add this in a comment but it was too long so I edited this post sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse aliases in the same SELECT clause

```
SELECT SUM(currentbalance) AS 'current', 
       SUM(principal) AS 'prin', 
       SUM(currentbalance + principal) AS 'total'
FROM dbase
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [juergen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123895/5817001) better, but you could add using aliases if you put it in a subquery.

```
SELECT [current] + [prin]
FROM (
    SELECT 
      SUM(currentbalance) AS 'current',
      SUM(principal) AS 'prin'
    FROM dbase ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my slack buddy here is the way to handle this. Makes all the sense now.

```
SELECT
  portfolio, 
  dateplaced, 
  file_principal,
  total_cash_cleared,
  IF(total_cash_cleared <> 0, file_principal / total_cash_cleared, 0) AS div_result,
  total_cash_pending,
  30_days,
  60_days,
  90_days
FROM
  (SELECT a.portfolio
       ,a.dateplaced
         ,(SELECT SUM(chargedoffprincipal) FROM Dbase WHERE portfolio = a.portfolio ) AS 'file_principal'
         ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus IN ('POSTED','PROCCESED'), paymentamount, 0)) AS 'total_cash_cleared'
         ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING', paymentamount, 0)) AS 'total_cash_pending'
         ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '30_days'
         ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '60_days'
         ,SUM(IF(b.paymentstatus = 'PENDING' AND YEAR(paymentdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(paymentdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 MONTH),paymentamount, 0)) AS '90_days'
  FROM dbase a
  LEFT JOIN payments b
  ON a.filenumber = b.filenumber
  GROUP BY a.portfolio
) AS original_query
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(original_query.dateplaced, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC
```